# Open a file with a pre-defined function (with method)

Tags: python, file-io

I have a predefined function that I am currently running to check if a file a input is correct. I wish to open this file in my function with the with" operator. This is what I currently have:

```
def open_file():
'''Checks if the file is correct.'''
grab_file = True #Creates initial variable that checks if file is correct
while grab_file == True: #Loop initiates the check if true
    txt = input("Enter a file name: ") #Asks for file input
    try: 
        f = open(txt) #Tries to open the file
        return f #File returned as output
        grab_file = False #Stops the loop
    except: #File is invalid, prompts for retry
        print("Error. Please try again.")

def main():
'''Main function that runs through file and does delta calculations.'''
with open(open_file()) as f:
  f.readline()
  print_headers()
  pass
```

Not sure what exactly is the issue, thanks! *Note the second portion of the code is in its own main function and is not part of the open_file function.*

The code gives me an error when I try to run the following:

```
  f.readline()
  date = f.readline()
  print_headers()
```

> This is the error I am getting, the code after the `with open statement` are just a simple `readline(`
>
> ```
> "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper"
> ```

Comment: What's your question? You did not state what's wrong with the code. Does it raise an error? (Which? What is the traceback)? Does it produce an unexpected result? (What result does it produce and what was your expected output?). Does it crash (i.e. segmentation fault etc)?

Comment: This code states an error, because when I try to f.readline() it gives me a syntax error.

Comment: The `open_file` function has some issues but they are not related to the syntax error. Mainly: you have `grab_file = False` after a `return f` so it will never be done. Your use of `grab_file` isn't useful, just use `while True` (since that is what your code does anyway). Also: don't use `except:` Specify the type of exception: `except OSError`. Otherwise you are making your code way harder to debug trust me. The latter block of code is fine, you should really post more. Maybe you have an open parenthesis or something like that before that code that causes the syntax error.

Comment: "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper" This is the error I am getting, the code after the with open statement are just a simple readline()

Comment: That's not a syntax error. The issue is that your `open_file` function already opens the file and returns the file object and you are passing the return value to `open`. Either you just return the filename (but that would make `open_file` completely useless) or you just do `with open_file() as f` without doing `open(open_file())`.

Comment: Read about [Context Manager Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager)

Answer (score 0):

Your error is a fairly easy fix:
just replace the

```
with open(open_file()) as f:
```

with

```
with open_file() as f:
```

because you've already opened the file and returned the open file in the open_file() function.

However the print_headers() function doesn't exist in standard python 3.x so I'm not quite sure if this is your own function or a different mistake.